# Can I boot from a USB if I have issues with my desktop's current OS?

Tags: boot, usb

I've had times when I messed up Ubuntu by installing stuff to the point where I can't start it up normally. I always kind of felt it wasn't so bad because if I messed up my computer I can just do a clean install via USB. Now I'm wondering if there is some point where that won't be possible.

At what point would I not be able to boot via USB? Is there any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is no physical damage to your system, USB drive or damage to BIOS, etc. it is unlikely you will loose the ability to boot from USB.

Edit: This is my experience in over ten years of booting flash drives.

Comment: Well if there is physical damage to his first boot device he would still be able to boot off USB assuming his motherboard supports it. I have booted off a usb when the internal hard disk was broken.

Comment: Yes, most modern computers see a USB boot device as just another hard drive. I probably meant damage to motherboard, USB socket, power source, etc.